# Media queries inside CSS classes

Tags: css

So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
.myClass
{
    @media all (max-width: 1024px) {
        left: 33%;
    }
    @media all (min-width:1025px) {
        left: 25%;
    } 
}
```

but for some reason isn't working. Is there any way I could achieve this?

EDIT: I know that you can achieve that by putting the media queries outside, but I don't want to do that =(

Comment: Nope. You'll need two definitions for `.myClass`.

Comment: while that is indeed invalid css, it would work in less. Just save that as a .less file and run it trough a compiler to turn it into css. http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-directives-and-bubbling

Comment: This question has four almost identical answers.  Perhaps three of them should be deleted?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're trying to set the `media queries` inside a class.

You have to set them outside any class and inside the querys you could override your classes you want to change on different views.

> To learn more About `media-queries` take a look at [its documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```
.myClass
{
   // default style
}

@media all (max-width: 1024px)
{
    .myClass {
        left: 33%;
    }
}

@media all (min-width:1025px) {
    .myClass {
        left: 25%;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem's core lies in the syntax of CSS statements. There are two kinds of statement in CSS:

- CSS rules(i.e. rulesets)
- At-rules

`@media` is a type of at-rule. CSS rules can be nested inside `@media`. But inside a CSS rule `$media` or any other at-rule can't be nested in a syntactically valid way and thus if it's done so, it is ignored.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax#CSS_statements
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule

Answer (score 0):

In think you shoudl use

```
 @media all (max-width: 1024px) {
     .myClass  {
        left: 33%;
      }
 }

@media all (min-width:1025px) {
     .myClass  {
        left: 25%;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is not valid in CSS. You should use:

```
@media all (max-width: 1024px) {
    .myClass{
        left: 33%;
    }
}
@media all (min-width:1025px) {
    .myClass{
        left: 25%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with the followings:

```
   @media (max-width: 1024px) {
      .myClass {
        left: 33%;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1025px) {
      .myClass {
        left: 25%;
      }
    }
```